# View all button not showing all products magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, products

When clicked on '**View All**' button, at the bottom of the page, it does not show all products.

My web site : http://dev.essethelabel.com/clothing.html

Comment: you need to check your product block from where the collection gets loaded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set a default limit pagination in admin, check this through Magento Admin panel. for more informations about [pagination](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/how-to-add-view-all-button-in-magentos-pagination/)